# c++ how count characters from user input?

Tags: c++, char

I have to ask the user for their name and the count the letters in each name they enter.

This is my code and it works for two names but I was wondering what if the user puts three names. How can I improve this or I want to know a better way to do this.

```
int x1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;
char name;
cout << "What is your name? : ";
while (cin.get(name) )
{

    if (name == 32)
    {

        x2 = x1;
        x1 = 0;

    }
    else if (name == '\n')
    {
        x1 -= 1;
        break;
    }
    x1++;
}
cout << x2 << " " << x1 << endl;
```

Comment: What characters, and what encoding? In UTF-8  `é` or  `π` is one character, but several bytes!

Comment: If you can't use STL containers then use a char array, [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cout << "Enter your name: ";
string name;
getline(cin, name);
cout << "There are " << name.length() << " letters in your name.\n";
```

Comment: Won't work for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) names, like `СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ` (my family name in Russian, i.e. cyrillics)

Comment: For use with non-ASCII characters, `std::string` won't work.  A different string would need to be used, such as `std::wstring`.

Comment: No, `std::string` works with UTF-8. It is just that `.length()` or `.size()` give the number of bytes, which is not the number of characters!